# Opacity in IE 8

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I'm trying to implement the opacity for IE 8. Currently I use this code to achieve opacity:

```
background-clip: padding-box; 
background-color: #FFFFFF;
border: 5pt solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
color: #BBBBBB;
height: auto; max-width: 800px;
```

Comment: Your code is not supported on IE8.

Comment: very VERY first google-result for "opacity ie8": http://www.quirksmode.org/css/opacity.html

Answer (score 2):

IE 8 doesn't [support rgba colours](http://caniuse.com/#search=rgba).

The only opacity it supports is whole-element-opacity via the proprietary `filter` CSS property.

Comment: @dean — What code? IE8 doesn't support anything that would let you achieve what your code does in a modern browser.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is not supported in IE8.

If you want to use Opacity filter on IE you should use this:

```
filter: alpha(opacity = 50);
```

Comment: it doesn't work on Border.. we are talking about Opacity. IE8 doesn't support border opacity. All people here saying the same thing to you.